# How to access parent layout without id from child textview with id programatically in android fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, setbackground

I am now trying to change the background color of the parent layout of the textview given the id inside the fragment.
Is it possible to dynamically call the parent layout with the child textview and change the background color without giving the parent an id?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/actv_notify_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray_7f"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="진료" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

This is xml code.

I thought maybe there is a .parent() function just like a jquery selector.

Comment: Can you specify the kotlin code where are you going to use this? Recyclerview?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. Unlike javascript, Java and Kotlin are not very friendly with types.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calling parents on child view and cast that view accordingly. In this case, your child view name is `actv_notify_all` and its parent is a `LinearLayoutCompat` without any ID.

```
val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.actv_notify_all)
(textView.parent as LinearLayoutCompat).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
```